# submit a form with file not working using django ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, form-data

Upload image beside other data when user submit the form. using formData in jquery.

- I added  picture field to the model
- added picture element in the form
- added the input tag  in the html
- send the data through AJAX  to the view
- getting the data from ajax request and added to the view function

the system display error :

**valid form
Internal Server Error: /create/te2chira**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\LT
>   GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\LT GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py",
>   line 296, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: **blog_te2chira.num
>   n**

## models.py

```
class te2chira(models.Model):
    te2chira_id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True)
    num = models.IntegerField()
    # year = models.IntegerField()
    te2chira_date = models.DateField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='DEFAULT VALUE', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='DEFAULT VALUE', blank=True, null=True)
    is_sent=models.IntegerField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pictures/%d/%m/%Y/',null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.te2chira_id)
```

## form.py

```
from django import forms
from blog.models import te2chira, destination

class SaveTe2chira(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = te2chira
        fields = ['title', 'description','picture' ]
```

## html

```
<form method="POST" class="form-style-9" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
<li>
 <input type="file" id="img" name="img"/>   
</li>
<li>
<input type="submit" class="field-style field-full align-none" id="save" value="save" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function(){
                $('#save').on('click',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault()
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('num',$('#num').val())
                    formData.append('title',$('#title').val())
                    formData.append('text',$('#text').val())
                    formData.append('issent', 0)
                    formData.append('img', document.getElementById('img').files[0])



                $.ajax({
                    url:'/create/te2chira',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:formData,
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    headers:{
                        'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
                    }
                }).done(function(msg) {
                    document.location = "/creativePageSend.html"
                    alert('data saved')


                }).fail(function(err){
                    alert('no data was saved')
                })
            })
        })
</script>

</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

## views.py

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = SaveTe2chira(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("valid form")
            form.save()
            id=form.te2chira_id
            print(id)
            request.session['idTe2chira']=id
            return render(request,'./creativePageSend.html',{'id':id})
        else:
            print("invalid form")
```

Upload the image with all the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Error is called because fields like num,te2chira_date,is_sent are empty.

set default values for it or `blank=True, null=True`
and migrate it

Answer (score 0):

Your Django form only has the fields `['title', 'description','picture' ]` but your HTML form is posting `['title', 'num', 'text', 'img', 'issent']`. So your form is basically only setting `title` and is valid because `description` and `picture` can be `blank`.

When you save your form, the model instance only has `title` set, all other fields are blank, which is not allowed according to your model definition.

You should make your HTML fields names match the form fields names and also make sure before you save your form (and the model) that all mandatory model fields have a value.